# Check if string starts with a substring in D / phobos?

Tags: d, phobos

I haven't so far found how I can most easily check if a string starts with a certain character in D.

I want something like:

```
if (my_str.startswith("/")) {
    // Do something
}
```

The closest I found was "chompPrefix" ([here](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html)), but that is not really what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a startsWith in std.algorithm that will work just like that.

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
void main() {
    string my_str = "/test";
    if(my_str.startsWith("/"))
        writeln("cool");
}
```

Comment: Ah, obviously I missed to google "startswith site:dlang.org" :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I gues also this is working:

```
string temp = "sometemp";
assert(temp[0..2] == "so")
```